# Very simple account management Java

Tags: java, string, account

I am trying to create a very simple account system where a user can create an account and "login" to an account that they have created. At the moment after the user inputs their details I add the account to a text file like so;

```
public void createAccount(UserInfo createdUser) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("auctionAccounts.txt"));
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(createdUser);
    objectOutputStream.flush();
    objectOutputStream.close();
}
```

I have now moved onto the "login" method, and I am struggling to find a way to loop through the objects stored in the textfile to see if an account exists. I just want to do a very simple compare such as;

```
if(enteredUsername == textfile.username){
 if(enteredPassword == textfile.password){
    //Do something
 }
}
```

Obviously that is the simple pseudo code, I am teaching myself Java and haven't come across a way to loop through a text file at the moment. I understand that I could probably use an ArrayList of accounts, but I would like it if when the user comes back to my program after exiting their account would still exist.

Many thanks

Comment: How are you storing the objects in the file? Could you post an example of the text file?

Comment: Your `createAccount` method always opens the file from the start, meaning that there will always be just one account in the file - the latest one. I suggest going through a tutorial about [creating, reading and writing files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html).

Comment: Actually at the moment the formatting of the stored account is very messed up, here is an examples of a username, "TestAccount", and a password, "TestPassword";

`¬í sr UserInfoó0‡´ù±´ L passWordt Ljava/lang/String;L userNameq ~ xpt TestPasswordt TestUsername`

Comment: Yes, because you chose to use ObjectOutputStream, which uses serialization, rather than a simple text file. I repeat my suggestion.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your suggestion, I will read through the tutorial you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You have to read your `UserInfo` from your file using `FileInputStream` and [`ObjectFileInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html). Then you have to iterate over the objects you read and compare the username and the password. Something like this should work:

```
ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("auctionAccounts.txt"));
UserInfo user = null;

while (user = (UserInfo) input.readObject() != null) {
  if(user.username.equals(enteredPassword) && user.password.equals(enteredPassword)) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

You have to compare `String` instances with equal. See: [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

As @RealSkeptic explained you don't append to the file. You recreate it every time add a `UserInfo`.

Last but not least: Don't use such naive code with real users. At least you should created salted hashes of the passwords.

Comment: Thankyou for your help, I will have a look at the material you suggested.